# In a C function declaration, what does "..." as the last parameter do?

Tags: c, syntax, function, parameters

Often I see a function declared like this:

```
void Feeder(char *buff, ...)
```

what does "..." mean?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It allows a variable number of arguments of unspecified type (like `printf` does).

You have to access the arguments with the `va_start`, `va_arg` and `va_end` functions.

See http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html or [Where in the C standard variadic functions are described?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34577745/112968) for more information

Answer (score 23):

[Variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varargs.h#.3Cvarargs.h.3E)

> Variadic functions are functions which may take a variable number of arguments
>   and are declared with an ellipsis in place of the last parameter.
>   An example of such a function is `printf`.
>
> A typical declaration is
>
> ```
>     int check(int a, double b, ...);
> ```
>
> Variadic functions must have at least one named parameter, so, for instance,
>
> ```
>     char *wrong(...);
> ```
>
> is not allowed in C.

Answer (score 7):

The three dots '...' are called an ellipsis. Using them in a function makes that function a *variadic* function.
To use them in a function declaration means that the function will accept an arbitrary number of parameters after the ones already defined.

For example:

```
Feeder("abc");
Feeder("abc", "def");
```

are all valid function calls, however the following wouldn't be:

```
Feeder();
```

Answer (score 7):

variadic function (multiple parameters)

[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D)

```
#include <stdarg.h>

double average(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    double tot = 0;
    va_start(ap, count); //Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address)
    for(j=0; j<count; j++)
        tot+=va_arg(ap, double); //Requires the type to cast to. Increments ap to the next argument.
    va_end(ap);
    return tot/count;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Functions with `...` as last parameter are called Variadic functions (Cppreference. 2016). This `...` is used to allow variable length parameters with unspecified types.

We can use variadic functions when we are not sure about the number of parameters or their types.

**Example of variadic function:**
Let us assume we need a sum function that will return the summation of variable number of arguments. We can use a variadic function here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int sum(int count, ...)
{
    int total, i, temp;
    total = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        temp = va_arg(args, int);
        total += temp;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[3] = {5, 10, 15};
    // Get summation of all variables of the array
    int sum_of_numbers = sum(3, numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);
    printf("Sum of the array %d\n", sum_of_numbers);
    // Get summation of last two numbers of the array
    int partial_sum_of_numbers = sum(2, numbers[1], numbers[2]);
    printf("Sum of the last two numbers of the array %d\n", partial_sum_of_numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image: C output]

**Practice problem:** A simple problem to practice variadic function can be found in [hackerrank practice problem here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variadic-functions-in-c/problem)

**Reference:**

- Cppreference. (2016, February 13). Variadic functions. Retrieved July
  25, 2018, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic

Answer (score 6):

It means that a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D) is being declared.

Answer (score 1):

- `...` = three dot = three point = called: `ellipsis`

  - means: **variable** number of parameters

    - compared to normal function: **fixed** (number of named) parameter
- function with `...` para is called: [Variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_C)

## Variadic function

### Definition

- valid:

  - `int validFunctionWithNamedParameterThenEllipsis(int a, double b, ...);`
- invalid

  - `int invalidFunctionOnlyEllipsis(...);`

### Example

popular case:

```c
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

call:

```c
printf("year=%d, name=%s", 2021, "crifan");
```

->

- `format` == `"year=%d, name=%s"`

  - named parameter
- `...` == `2021, "crifan"`

  - variable number of parameter

    - here total **2** parameter

      - first: integer type `2021`
      - second: string type `"crifan"`

### How to get/calculate paremeter for Variadic function

- core logic: use `va_list`, with `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`

#### Related definition

```c
#include <stdarg.h>

void va_start(va_list ap, last_arg);
type va_arg(va_list ap, type);
void va_end(va list ap);
```

#### Example

##### average

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double average(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    double sum = 0;

    va_start(ap, count); /* Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address) */
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        sum += va_arg(ap, int); /* Increments ap to the next argument. */
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return sum / count;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("%f\n", average(3, 1, 2, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

##### maxof

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int maxof(int, ...) ;
void f(void);

main(){
        f();
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int maxof(int n_args, ...){
        register int i;
        int max, a;
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, n_args);
        max = va_arg(ap, int);
        for(i = 2; i <= n_args; i++) {
                if((a = va_arg(ap, int)) > max)
                        max = a;
        }

        va_end(ap);
        return max;
}

void f(void) {
        int i = 5;
        int j[256];
        j[42] = 24;
        printf("%d\n",maxof(3, i, j[42], 0));
}
```

##### execl

```c
#include <stdarg.h>

#define  MAXARGS     31

/*
 * execl is called by
 * execl(file, arg1, arg2, ..., (char *)(0));
 */
int execl(const char *file, const char *args, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char *array[MAXARGS +1];
    int argno = 0;

    va_start(ap, args);
    while (args != 0 && argno < MAXARGS)
    {
        array[argno++] = args;
        args = va_arg(ap, const char *);
    }
    array[argno] = (char *) 0;
    va_end(ap);
    return execv(file, array);
}
```

##### My case: hook syscall()

```c
/*==============================================================================
 Hook: syscall()
==============================================================================*/

int syscall(int, ...);

// normally max number of syscall parameter is not exceed 8
// refer: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/bsd/kern/syscalls.master
int MaxSupportArgNum_syscall = 16;

%hookf(int, syscall, int number, ...){
    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_stat64: number=%d", number);

    // Setting up some variables to get all the parameters from syscall
    void *paraPtr, *paraList[MaxSupportArgNum_syscall];
//    char *paraPtr, *paraList[MaxSupportArgNum_syscall];
    va_list argList;
    int curParaNum = 0;

    va_start(argList, number);
    while ((paraPtr = (void *) va_arg(argList, void *))) {
    //    while ((paraPtr = (char *) va_arg(argList, char *))) {
        paraList[curParaNum] = paraPtr;
        curParaNum += 1;
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_stat64: [%d] paraPtr=%p", curParaNum, paraPtr);
    }
    va_end(argList);

//    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_stat64: argList=%{public}s", argList);
    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_stat64: curParaNum=%d", curParaNum);

    bool isStat = (SYS_stat == number);
    bool isStat64 = (SYS_stat64 == number);
    if (isStat || isStat64){
        char* curPath = (char *)paraList[0];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_stat64: isStat=%{bool}d, isStat64=%{BOOL}d, curPath=%{public}s", isStat, isStat64, curPath);
        
        bool isJbPath = isJailbreakPath(curPath);
        if (isJbPath){
            os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_stat64: IS jailbreak path: %{public}s", curPath);
            return OPEN_FAILED;
        } else {
            os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_stat64: NOT jailbreak path: %{public}s", curPath);
        }
    }

//    return %orig;
//    return %orig(number, ...);
//    int retValue = %orig();

//    int retValue = callOriginSyscall(number, curParaNum, paraList);
////    int retValue = callOriginSyscall(number, curParaNum, (void *)paraList);
//    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_stat_file: retValue=%d", retValue);
//    return retValue;

    int paraNum = curParaNum;

    int syscallRetValue = -1;

    if (0 == paraNum){
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number);
    } else if (1 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p", para1);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1);
    } else if (2 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p", para1, para2);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2);
    } else if (3 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        void* para3 = paraList[2];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p,para3=%p", para1, para2, para3);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2, para3);
    } else if (4 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        void* para3 = paraList[2];
        void* para4 = paraList[3];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p,para3=%p,para4=%p", para1, para2, para3, para4);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2, para3, para4);
    } else if (5 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        void* para3 = paraList[2];
        void* para4 = paraList[3];
        void* para5 = paraList[4];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p,para3=%p,para4=%p,para5=%p", para1, para2, para3, para4, para5);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2, para3, para4, para5);
    } else if (6 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        void* para3 = paraList[2];
        void* para4 = paraList[3];
        void* para5 = paraList[4];
        void* para6 = paraList[5];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p,para3=%p,para4=%p,para5=%p,para6=%p", para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6);
    } else if (7 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        void* para3 = paraList[2];
        void* para4 = paraList[3];
        void* para5 = paraList[4];
        void* para6 = paraList[5];
        void* para7 = paraList[6];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p,para3=%p,para4=%p,para5=%p,para6=%p,para7=%p", para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6, para7);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6, para7);
    } else if (8 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        void* para3 = paraList[2];
        void* para4 = paraList[3];
        void* para5 = paraList[4];
        void* para6 = paraList[5];
        void* para7 = paraList[6];
        void* para8 = paraList[7];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p,para3=%p,para4=%p,para5=%p,para6=%p,para7=%p,para8=%p", para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6, para7, para8);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6, para7, para8);
    } else if (9 == paraNum){
        void* para1 = paraList[0];
        void* para2 = paraList[1];
        void* para3 = paraList[2];
        void* para4 = paraList[3];
        void* para5 = paraList[4];
        void* para6 = paraList[5];
        void* para7 = paraList[6];
        void* para8 = paraList[7];
        void* para9 = paraList[8];
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: para1=%p,para2=%p,para3=%p,para4=%p,para5=%p,para6=%p,para7=%p,para8=%p,para9=%p", para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6, para7, para8, para9);
        syscallRetValue = %orig(number, para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6, para7, para8, para9);
    }

    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "hook_syscall_orig: syscallRetValue=%d", syscallRetValue);
    return syscallRetValue;
}
```

#### Some Note

##### va_start

when call `va_start`, `last_arg` is the last named parameter, NOT the first one

for: `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);`

- correct

  - `va_start(argList, oflag);`
- wrong

  - `va_start(argList, path);`

    - (XCode's clang) compiler will warning

      - `Second argument to 'va_start' is not the last named parameter`

##### va_arg

`type va_arg(va_list ap, type);`

for pass `type`, there is a special case:

when pass in :

- char
- unsigned char
- unsigned short

but return always is:

- **unsigned int**

-> so when code:

`curPara = (mode_t) va_arg(argList, mode_t);`

according:

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

-> `mode_t`==`unsigned short`

equivalent to:

`curPara = (mode_t) va_arg(argList, unsigned short);`

so compiler warning:

`Second argument to 'va_arg' is of promotable type 'mode_t' (aka 'unsigned short'); this va_arg has undefined behavior because arguments will be promoted to 'int'`

change to:

`curPara = (mode_t) va_arg(argList, unsigned int);`

could avoid warning.

## Related Doc

- [The C Book — Variable numbers of arguments (gbdirect.co.uk)](https://publications.gbdirect.co.uk//c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)
- [Variadic function - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D)
- [<stdarg.h> (opengroup.org)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdarg.h.html)
- [stdarg.h - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h#Declaring_variadic_functions)
- [C Library - <stdarg.h> (tutorialspoint.com)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdarg_h.htm)