# pass many arguments to a C function

Tags: c, function, arguments

How can I pass many arguments to a C function?
Assuming that I have this function:

```
void f(int n, char* a, char* b, ...)
```

I want an undefined number of char* arguments. How can I do so?

Comment: You need to make a variadic function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735587/in-a-c-function-declaration-what-does-as-the-last-parameter-do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you needs is called variable number of argument functions, you can read from : [9.9. Variable numbers of arguments](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) a good and essay tutorial.

A **short theory in four points** will help you to understand my code:

1. the `<stdarg.h>` header file must be included, his introduces a new
   type, called a va_list, and three functions that operate on objects
   of this type, called `va_start, va_arg, and va_end`.
2. `va_start:` is a macro to set `arg_ptr` to beginning of list `ap` of
   optional arguments
3. `va_arg:` does is use this saved stack pointer, and extract the
   correct amount of bytes for the type provided
4. `va_end:` is a  macro to reset `ap`, After all arguments have been
   retrieved, `va_end` resets the pointer to NULL.

This theory is not enough but below an example (as you required) will help you to understand basic work-flow/ and steps: (*read comment for each 4 steps*)

```
//Step1: Need necessary header file
#include <stdarg.h>     
void f(int first, char* a, char* b, ...){   
    va_list ap;  // vlist variable
    int n;       // number 
    char aa,     
    int i;
    float f;
   //print fix numbers of arguments
    printf("\n %d, %s, %s\n", first, a, b);

   //Step2: To initialize `ap` using right-most argument that is `b` 
    va_start(ap, b); 

   //Step3: Now access vlist `ap`  elements using va_arg()
     n = va_arg(ap, int); //first value in my list gives number of ele in list 
     while(n--){
       aa = (char)va_arg(ap, int); // notice type, and typecast
       i = va_arg(ap, int);
       f = (float)va_arg(ap, double);   
       printf("\n %c %d %f \n", aa,i, f);
    }

    //Step4: Now work done, we should reset pointer to NULL
    va_end(ap); 
}
int main(){
    char* a = "Aoues";
    char* b = "Guesmi";
    f(2, a, b, 3, 'a', 3, 6.7f, 'b', 5, 5.5f, 'A', 0, 0.1);
    //         ^ this is `n` like count in variable list
    return 1;
}
```

Who does it runs:

```
~$ ./a.out 
 2, Aoues, Guesmi
 a 3 6.700000 
 b 5 5.500000 
 A 0 0.100000
```

A **brief explanation of my code** will be helpful for future users:

1. Actually function is fixed number of arguments followed by variable
   number of arguments. And right-most argument to function (in fixed
   argument list that is `char* b` in our function `f()`) uses just to
   initialized viable list `ap`.
2. The function `f()` above fist reads `n` value that is `3` (*read
   comment in main*).     In `f()`,  `while(n--)` executes for three
   time and each time in loop using `va_arg()` macro we retrieves three
   values.
3. If you notice I reads first two `ints` then a `double`, Where as I
   am sending `char, int, float` (*notice in main where I call f()*).
   this is because auto type promote in case of variable argument list.
   (read in detail from above lisk)

Her is one more useful link from MSDN: [va_arg, va_end, va_start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

(*let me know if you need more help regarding this*)

Comment: May I suggest, for the sake of demonstrating that the number of arguments passed is based around the `n=3` you pointed out in your code, that the three groups of arguments `'a',3,6.7f`, `'b',5,5.5f`, `'A',0,0.1` be in struct pointer form: `fun(2, a, b, 3, &(struct foo) { .aa='a', .i=3, .f=6.7f }, /* newline here */ &(struct foo) { .aa='b', .i=5, .f=5.5f }, /* newline here */ &(struct foo) { .aa='A', .i=0, .f=0.1f });`

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Yes , really nice suggestion man. But for OP I want to keep code bit simple. I included different datatypes because I want to demonstration that `char` promote up to  `int`, `float` promote up to `double`.  only. If you are writing a code like you suggesting then put that code on codepas and give me the link :)..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use varargs (look this up yourself, the stuff the callee uses to read the args is in `stdarg.h`).

Note that there is no way for the callee to automatically determine the number of arguments actually passed. So for example it might be `n`, and you just have to trust the caller to get `n` right.