# Where in the C standard variadic functions are described?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, variadic-functions, c11

I was searching for a description of the variadic functions in the C11 standard but the only information I found was barely mentioning the topic. Can someone show me reference to all topics about them that can be found in it?

What I've found myself so far is in §6.9.1.8:

> If a function that accepts a variable number of arguments is defined
>   without a parameter type list that ends with the ellipsis notation,
>   the behavior is undefined.

And in §7.16 which describes the `<stdarg.h>` header file. However I highly doubt this is all the information which can be found about variadic functions in the standard.

Comment: There are some more paragraphs relating to this. Basically, arguments passed for `...` in the parameter list are treated as if the function was defined without a prototype (i.e. default argument promotions apply). But more isn't really needed to specify variable argument lists.

Comment: You'll of course need `<stdarg.h>` in order to consume the variable arguments.

Comment: C11 draft standard, `6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along with the chapters you pointed, I would recommend to check chapter §6.7.6.3 from `C11` standard, which has some more information on *Function declarators*. To summarize,

- Variadic function declaration : Chapter §6.7.6.3
- Variadic function calls : Chapter §6.5.2.2
- Variadic function definitions : Chapter §6.9.1
- Variadic function argument list related macros and their usage: Chapter §7.16.1.1 - §7.16.1.4

However, there is no full-featured description of the variadic functions, compiled in the form of a complete chapter (if that is what you're looking for) in the standard itself, AFAIK.

You may want to have a look at the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) to gain some more insight.

Comment: How are they supposed to be supported by compiler developers then?

Comment: @FISOCPP I did not get you. There are enough information to support a variadic function present in the standard, it's just not in the form of a _complete chapter_ or tutorial. May I ask which particular information you're looking for?