# C passing ... to a function

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on making a version of printf in an embedded system that will print over a variety of interfaces. I am using snprintf to create the string and then sending it out over the interface. My curiosity is what the "..." being passed into the function is. The printf that I am using looks like, this is taken from an embedded printf library

```
void u_printf(const char* format, ...)
```

In this case the ... is some number of assorted variables passed into the function. But if I want to write my own version of this how do I get those variables passed in so I can then pass them on to snprintf.

```
void u_printf(const char* format, ...){
    int cx;
    char buffer[100];
    cx = x_snprintf(buffer, 100, format, ??);
    // function to send buffer to interface goes here    
}
```

So how do I go about getting the ... variables passed in to where the ?? mark is? Thanks!

Some quick help revealed that `va_list` is the answer here. When the ... is present we can grab the arguments passed in by creating `va_list va` variable. This can then be used or passed to `vsnprintf()`

Comment: Look up *variadic functions*

Comment: If you provide C-ellipsis version, provide also version with [`va_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_list) (as [vprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf)).

Comment: Search for `va_list` on the duplicate's web page

Comment: @StoryTeller I somewhat disagree with the question you chose as a duplicate. I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735587/in-a-c-function-declaration-what-does-as-the-last-parameter-do is much closer to what is asked here. Though there is an answer to this question in the linked one.

Comment: va_list it is. I started looking into it right after I posted. I guess posting the question helped me to summarize my problem. Thanks for the help!