# What is the (...) called in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, terminology, ellipsis, variadic

One of the uses of `...` is to denote *variadic* entities in C and C++.

- What is its name?
- Is it classified as an operator or something else when used that way?
- Any other details regarding `...`?

**Edit:** I know the purpose of `...`. I am asking about its name and classification, which I hope, is similar in C and C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a C function declaration, what does "..." as the last parameter do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735587/in-a-c-function-declaration-what-does-as-the-last-parameter-do)

Comment: C variadic functions and C++ variadic template arguments are completely different, can you give context in which you found it? (PS, C/C++ doesn't exist, please pick one)

Comment: I just want to know its name and classification

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is one of the **punctuators**.

> ```text
> 6.4.6  Punctuators
> Syntax punctuator:
>      one of  [    ]    (    )    {   }    .    ->
>              ++   --   &    *    +   -    ~    !
>              /    %    <<   >>   <   >    <=   >=    ==   !=   ^   |   &&   ||
>              ?    :    ;    ...
>              =    *=   /=   %=   +=  -=   <<=  >>=   &=   ^=   |=
>              ,    #    ##
>              <:   :>   <%   %>   %:   %:%:
> ```

In the function declaration it is called the ***ellipsis***.

---

Ellipsis is also used by some compiler `C` language extensions.
Example - gcc switch/case range extension

```
const char *test(unsigned num)
{
    switch(num)
    {
        case 0 ... 9:
            return "the value is in the 0 to 9 range";
        case 10 ... 99:
            return "the value is in the 10 to 99 range";
        default:
            return "out of tested range";
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YBLma-

Comment: However, as one of the comments in my question mentioned about parameter packs, why didn't you mention it in your answer?

Comment: Link to the C11 Standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.6

Comment: @ArdentCoder: It's still called an ellipsis in C++, even for parameter packs.

Comment: I would add that `...` is _not_ an operator, because it cannot form part of an _expression_ (in the sense of 'expression' defined by [C11 §6.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5)).  It has more in common with  `{` `}` and `;` than with the other punctuators.

Comment: @zwol In C++ the token `...` can be part of an expression. But it's not considered an _operator_ by the formal syntax.

Comment: @ArdentCoder Fold expressions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Answer (score 13):

The `...` is referred to as an *ellipsis* both in English and in the C standard.

Answer (score 7):

> One of the uses of ... is to denote variadic entities in C and C++.`

Yes, In layman's terms `...` can be thought of as denoting more than one or multiples (as in pseudo-code punctuation we sometimes use multiple dots to resemble different types) of a use case, for which if we consider variadics (being multiple in the sense of 'varying' arguments/parameters) in C++, it would refer to a variable number of arguments for functions or templates.

> What is its name?

***Ellipsis***

> Is it classified as an operator or something else when used in that way?

No, it's definitely not an operator as it allows you to *pass* any number of arguments, not *operate* on them.

> Any other details regarding ...?

As far as I know -

1. Its a special specifier;
2. The ellipsis always comes last in the argument list;
3. As far as its usage is concerned, its only used when you want to remove the limits on the number of parameters for a template/function or when you require to have an extensible number of parameters for expansion. (i.e. it provides parameter pack expansion in a variadic class template or function template) In practice we mostly require a fixed set of known parameters, so it isn't applicable to most cases;
4. It can be used with `sizeof` operator, as it's classified as a pack expansion as well.

> **Edit:** I know the purpose of `...` I am asking about its name and classification, which I hope, is similar in both C and C++.

The name is same, but usage may vary for C++ and C.

Am only familiar with its use in the former language. (I remember having a HackerRank problem on *Variadics*, covering its utility.)

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of three full stops `...` is called an **ellipsis** in both C and C++

---

In C++, the ellipsis helps initialize and expand different kinds of **packs**.

- A *`parameter pack`* - when there is an *ellipsis* between the **type** and the **identifier**
  `Type ... identifier`
- A *`pack expansion`* - consists of a pattern and an *ellipsis*
  `pattern...`